# Does JMeter or Rest Assured give any suggestion to improve the performance of the API or suggestion to the response we get from API?

Tags: testing, jmeter, rest-assured

I am looking into if JMeter or Rest Assured give any suggestion to improve the performance of the API or suggestion on the response we get from API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, both of them are basically http client tools. You can't count on them for any suggesstions.